# comparing strings in arraylist 2d java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a 2d arraylist (I hope its arraylist) defined by

```
String table[][];
table = new String[7][7];
```

I added some strings and then I try to find objects by

```
int c = 0;
int v = 0;

for (int s = 0; s < 49; s++) {
    if (s != 0) {    
        c++;
    }

    if (c == 6) {
        v++;
        c -= 6;
    }

    boolean check = table[c][v].equals("highlited");

    if (check) {
        System.out.println("got one");
    }
}
```

but my program doesn't work, any ideas? 
I am sorry for all the mistakes I have made, I am new in world of programing.

Comment: You have no ArrayList objects in the code you included.  They are all arrays.

Comment: Why don't you just use two nested loops, each running from 0 to 6, and checking every location in the array?

Comment: How are you setting the strings in the array?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work" - do you get an error? Unexpected output? How are you adding the strings?

Answer (score 1):

Using a debugger and printing the values of c and v will show that you are not covering the hole matrix but missing the last column (see image below)

[image]

there are many ways to check the content of a matrix, I will suggest a double for loop

```
int k = 7;
String table[][];
table = new String[k][k];
int c = 0;
int v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
    boolean check = table[c][v].equals("highlited");
    if (check) {
        System.out.println("got one");
    }
    }
}
```

or you can modify the snippet and do:

```
if (c == 7) {
    v++;
    c -= 7;
}
```

which makes more sense since the matrix is 7 multiple